# AmazonDynamoDBClient in Lambda - Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I use AmazonDynamoDBClient in the lambda to remove/insert an item into the dynamodb once the message arrives into the queue.
Here is the code for delete operation

```
    var request = new DeleteItemRequest()
                {
                    TableName = _tableName,
                    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                    {
                        { "Id", new AttributeValue() { S = id } }
                    }
                };
                await _client.DeleteItemAsync(request);
```

`_client` is set up as singleton in my DI container as well as the repository class communicating with dynamodb.

During load tests (around 1000 messages for 1 minute), it was found out that sometimes I might receive an exception `SSLStream: ObjectDisposedException`

```
One or more errors occurred. (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.) (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.) (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.) (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.) (Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.) ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at MyLambda.Repository.........
```

The same issue for insert btw

I watched at DynamoDb metrics: latency is really low (10ms) and no errors.
Is there anything I can try to do regarding this to fix the issue and avoid such errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a thorough investigation, I found that the root cause of this issue is lambda MemorySize settings.
I made an experiment with different MemorySize and got the following results:

- 128Mb - lot's of `SSLStream: ObjectDisposedException`
- 256Mb - noticeably a fewer exceptions
- 512Mb - no exceptions

For each case memory used by the application wasn't higher than 110Mb.

As a result of this, I came into the next conclusion: As AWS distributes CPU resources to each lambda depending on allocated memory, it means that  I/O operations and network traffic might also be affected by those setting.

Here are several blog posts confirming my thoughts:

- https://www.totalcloud.io/blog/aws-lambda-gotcha-you-must-know-before-configuring-them
- https://www.jeremydaly.com/15-key-takeaways-from-the-serverless-talk-at-aws-startup-day/